# What is $E[E[X|Y]|X]$? Could it be further simplified?

Tags: conditional-expectation

I am trying to figure out what $E[E[X|Y]|X]$ equals to. Could it be further simplified?

My initial guess is that it should be equal to X. However, I have no clue if it is correct.

I know $E[X|Y] = \int xf(x|y)\,dx$ and $E[E[X|Y]|X] = \int \int xf(x|y)\,dx f(y|x)\,dy$, but I am stuck here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You are on the right track. To simplify [[|]|], you can use the law of iterated expectations, which states that [[|]|]=[|]. This means that the conditional expectation of  given , taken over all possible values of , is equal to the unconditional expectation of , taken over all possible values of .

Using this result, we have:

[[|]|] = [|]

Now, we can simplify [|] using the definition of conditional expectation:

[|] = ∫(|)

where (|) is the conditional probability density function of  given . However, (|) is a Dirac delta function centered at , which means that it is equal to 1 when =, and 0 otherwise. Therefore, we have:

[|] = ∫(|) = ∫δ(−) =

where δ(−) is the Dirac delta function centered at .

Therefore, we have:

[[|]|] = [|] =

which confirms your initial guess. So, [[|]|] is equal to .

Comment: Hi Aditya. You could use the MathJax that this site supports to typeset your equations. For a quick start, please check [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).

Comment: The law of iterated expectations says $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$ but not $E[X|X] = E[E[X|Y]|X]$!

Comment: It is easy to construct counterexamples to negate your judgement, e.g., check the case when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.